# Shuffled range iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, range

In python3 `range` doesn't return a list but an iterator.

This is great and have some advantages such as not generating the whole list at once but only generating the elements when needed.

Now suppose that I want a range in a random order (basically a shuffled range). In python2 I'd just do:

```
my_list = range(n)
np.random.shuffle(my_list)
```

This won't work in python3. Once solution is to generate the actual list and then shuffling (which will then do the same as python2)

```
my_list = list(range(n))
np.random.shuffle(my_list)
```

But using this strategy we loose the advantage of the iterator.

Question: How can I create random ordered range iterator that will only give me indexes when requested?

Comment: Spontaneously I'd say you need a hash/encoding function which uniquely maps one value to another value in a range, e.g. `map(rot13, range(n))`. Obviously rot13 is inadequate here, and I'm not sure what other algorithm exactly qualifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the `shuffled` module?

```
pip3 install shuffled

>>> import shuffled
>>> my_list=shuffled.Shuffled(16)
>>> for i in my_list: print(i)
... 
2
14
15
1
4
5
3
0
7
10
11
6
8
9
12
13
>>> my_list=shuffled.Shuffled(16)
>>> for i in my_list: print(i)
... 
0
1
2
10
7
4
13
6
3
11
8
9
5
14
15
12
```

Comment: Looks like it's what I was looking for